# Beamer: \againframe inside other frame

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

I'd like to repeat a certain state of a frame in `beamer`.
Say like this:

```
\frame[label=A]{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1> foo
        \item<2> bar
    \end{itemize}
}

\frame{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1> fooagain
        \item<3> baragain
    \end{itemize}
    \only<2>\againframe<1>{A}
    \only<4>\againframe<2>{A}
}
```

However, this would not work as one can only call `\againframe` outside of other frames.

I would be fine with this constraint however, I don't want a mini frame for each frame I call again (with `\againframe`).

Do you know a solution for that?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the final intended layout of your output slides? I don't understand what you intend `\only<2>\againframe<1>{A}` to display. I think the answer you're looking for is based off of putting the entire contents in the first frame, then cleverly indexing the overlays, but without a clear concept of what you want as the final result, I can't provide that answer.

Comment: yea - it's quite difficult to describe my problem in a short example. I have some frames with a complicated pstricks image that is drawn step by step. Later I want to conclude my findings I had in these pstricks-frames. It seems quite stupid to me to have another mini frame for each time I show the final stage of an image-frame again in my concluding frame.

Comment: Did you finally find a solution for your question? Because I am looking for exactly the same thing, so it would be great if you could share your solution.

Comment: no, I didn't :-(

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want to achieve, but maybe it's this:

```
\frame<2,4>[label=A]{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1> fooagain
        \item<2> foo
        \item<3> baragain
        \item<4> bar
    \end{itemize}
}
\againframe<1-4>{A}
```

(I think this is also what @gotgenes has in mind.)

Comment: sorry guys - obviously my minimal example is more misleading than helping.

What I want to achieve is the following:

In my presentation I have a chapter with a lot of frames with different pstricks-graphics that all explain something. As they in fact explain pretty much, I'd like to have some kind of a summary frame in the end of the chapter. In this frame all the interesting findings are explained and - if necessary I'd like to repeat some previous frames in certain states. However I want the summary frame to appear as JUST ONE FRAME (with just one mini frame)

Comment: Oh, so you want something like a sort of thumbnail of a previous page? I have to admit my try would be to make a copy of your pdf and \includegraphics single pages of it.

Answer (score 3):

It has been quite some time since you have asked your question, but I hope this could be helpful for you and others. You have to label both frames like the following example:

```
\frame<-2>[label=A]{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> foo
        \item<2-> bar
    \end{itemize}
}

\frame<1>[label=B]{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> fooagain
        \item<2-> baragain
    \end{itemize}
}
\againframe<1>{A}
\againframe<2>{B}
\againframe<2>{A}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clear on what you would like, but would `newcommand` suffice?

```
\newcommand{\twolist}[2]{\begin{itemize}\item #1 \item #2 \end{itemize}}
\begin{document}
\frame{
  \twolist{foo}{bar}
}
\frame{
  \twolist{fooagain}{baragain}
  \twolist{foo}{bar}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought of \newcommand too, but it feels like there is a better way to do this.... (see also my comment above)