# Recalling a specific overlay of a tikzpicture in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I am making a presentation and I want to recall some pictures in my conclusion. The pictures are done using tikzpicture and are in separate files, with some overlay specifications. However, I want to recall only a specific overlay in the conclusion.

File: picture.tex

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw at (0,0) circle (1); 
\uncover<2->{
   \draw at (2,0) circle (1);}
\uncover<3->{
   \draw at (1,1) circle (1);}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then in my main file,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{The Picture}
Some text 
\begin{center}
\input{picture}
\end{center}
}

\frame{\frametitle{Conclusion}
\begin{center}
\input{picture}
\end{center}
}
```

I would like to display only the overlay <2> in the conclusion without recalling the whole frame (with \againframe). Is there any way of doing that or should I create another file with only what I want to display on the last frame?

Comment: Is Jakob's answer describes a solution for you http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51895/beamer-againframe-inside-other-frame ?

Comment: No because there are other things on the first slide actually, and I only want to recall the picture. I do not want to recall the whole slide, just a specific overlay of the picture. 
(I have edited my question to be clear.)

Comment: You could put the pictures into saveboxes and create multiple copies anywhere in the document.  (See \newsavebox, \savebox and \usebox.)

Comment: Apparently, there are incompatible with overlays. Moreover, I do not think it would work since in the conclusion, I call the picture within frame 1, while I want to show frame 2.

Comment: I think [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168705/1952) to `How to generate a series of \paused stand-alone TikZ images?` can help you. The idea would be to generate a series of `standaloneframe` frames and include the desired one in your last frame.

Comment: Mmmh... yes this would work, but I will have to generate additional .pdf files. In that case, I can also generate another .tex file that would be a copy of the first file but containing only the desired frame.

Comment: Your code won't compile here...

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood correctly, you wish to display all frames of the picture on the first slide but only the second frame on the second slide. If so, you can do this by specifying the slides to show as an optional argument to the `frame` environment for the second slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-picture.tex}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
    \uncover<2->{
      \draw (2,0) circle (1);}
    \uncover<3->{
      \draw (1,1) circle (1);}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{The Picture}
    Some text
    \begin{center}
      \input{\jobname-picture}
    \end{center}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}<2>{Conclusion}
    \centering
    \input{\jobname-picture}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Specifying frames of picture to show for a particular <code>beamer</code> <code>frame</code> environment]

Comment: It is not exactly what I wanted. I have done something similarly but it is not very elegant. The problem is that I had some frames on the conclusion slide and I wanted to recall say frame 2 of some picture within frame 4 of the conclusion. So I have cheated by starting the conclusion at frame 3, so that the frame numbers coincide.

Comment: @Homotopy Well you could include the text in the `tikzpicture` with an overlay specification which you won't use in the first slide and then specify overlay specifications accordingly for the remaining picture elements.